# Working of 2 input AND diode register?

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, logic-gates

According to the description that I am reading in book it says that you need to connect +Vcc to both the A and B in order to get the output 1 at Q.

[image]

I don't really understand this. What does the +Vcc mean here? and How does the Inputs work? To visualize this, does it mean that when both A and B will be positive when connected to +Vcc wire, if so then diode will be reversed biased as far as I know. But how will the output be 1?

Comment: What is the output voltage if you remove the diodes entirely?

Comment: Vcc is a reasonably common abbreviation for your power supply voltage rail.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Depends if the +Vcc means 1 or 0?

Comment: @user963241 The *voltage* does not depend on whether it's positive or negative logic! For this to be an AND gate, and not an OR gate, however, we know which it must be.

Answer (score 3):

+Vcc simply means the positive supply voltage.

The inputs work because when you connect A OR B to 0V they pull the output Q down to a LOW voltage. (typically 0.7V for silicon diodes). The current that can flow through them is limited by the size of the resistor, R.

What the book didn't mention was that if the inputs are not connected to anything the output Q will also be HIGH.

Comment: Is it not really an AND gate then if A = B = 0 and Q = 1?

Comment: If the outputs are not connected, they are not 0 - they are floating, which is not the same as 0 V. That's often an undefined state - if you take a real AND gate and don't connect the inputs to anything, how can you know what logic levels it sees?

Comment: No - Q will be LOW (Q = 0) when **either or both** the inputs are taken LOW. It is called an AND gate because to get Q = 1 **both inputs** (A AND B) need to be HIGH (or not connected = HIGH). Resistor - Diode logic is similar to TTL in that you have to pull the inputs down to ground in order to make them work

Comment: @Gregd'Eon In logic NOT 0 is 1 (by definition)

Comment: @Jim hmm. Floating definitely isn't always 1. In this particular circuit, floating is equivalent to 1, but in other circuits, that isn't true - I'm picturing CMOS gates, where floating means "0 or 1, depending on the random electric fields around the pins".

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I think you're confusing logic with the technology. **If** the question had been about CMOS (which is wasn't) then I would have pointed out that the floating input could have either value and needed to be tied through a resistor to +V or 0V. If you'd pictured a  TTL gate you would have to say that a floating input will be a '1'. I always try to answer the question **asked** and not the one I think it should have been. Now if the question had been about comparing different logic gate technologies ...

Comment: Meh, okay. I know what you mean. You can keep my +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If both inputs A and B are high (connected to +Vcc) or open (not connected anywhere) then current does not flow trough the diodes and Q is high (since it is connected to Vcc by R).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYF1LW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above shematic I think it is obvious that output is high.

If at least one input is connected to ground, then current passes through the diode and Q becomes low (since it is connected to ground via diode).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2lNmr.png)</sup>

Now D2 is connected to ground, current flows trough it and pulls the output down (because of the resistor). D1 is reverse biased and does not conduct.

Comment: If both inputs A and B are high and connected with Vcc, then doesn't the other side of diode become -ve? and how does that relate with +ve by R?

Comment: @user963241 I have added schematics to better show this.

Comment: Nice diagrams so +1 from me

Comment: @Pentium100: Where are the two inputs in this circuit?

Comment: @user963241 the inputs are the cathodes of the two diodes, just like in your circuit. I just drew the circuits as they would be if both inputs were connected to Vcc (first circuit) or one input connected to ground (second circuit).